# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]

I have a `common` and a `validators` package. In the `validators` `__init__.py` file I am trying to import the `boolean.py`, `date.py`, `json.py` files, but it says the common module is not found.

Comment: It appears as though the `validators/__init__` file does not have visibility to its parents.  Either hack the `sys.path` to *insert* the parent directories, or just `import boolean`, for example.

Comment: You can follow the answer given by @Shruthi Rajashekhar below. On the other hand,  `date`, `json` is Python's builtin. You may want to rename your files to something like `custom_date`, `custom_json` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply import as the files are in same folder:

`import boolean,date,json,numeric`

Comment: Use this with care, as some of these module names will shadow (or actually import) built-ins, leading to unexpected behaviour.